# CSS not applying to GitHubPage

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I made a portfolio page in Codepen and i'm trying to publish it with Gihub Pages.
I'm not able to make my CSS work. This is the link I made for the stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

And this is the link for the repository: https://github.com/IgnacioGR/IgnacioGR.github.io

I'm new in this so i'm sure I missed something.

Comment: please can you explain the details!

Answer (score 2):

Your "css" file has a error, the file extension is "ccs" not "css"
[look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clf9z.png)

Comment: Yeah, that was it, I was so tired and I guess I couldn't see that one. Thank you so much.